# Create Simple User Messaging Setup in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: .net, wcf, entity-framework

I want to setup a simple user messaging system via WCF and Entity Framework. I am keeping the idea simple:

A user can send a message another user.

Context: Bob sent Bill a Message. Bill sent Bob a Message. (Not threaded)

I have made an attempt after reading assorted advice via Googling heavily. The result is two classes `User` and `Message`.

I am getting rather confuses/stuck.  <strike>therefore my question is: IS my implementation flawed and if so is there a "better" way to implement this?</strike>

**User Class**

```
public class User
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Message> SentMessages { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Message> ReceivedMessages { get; set; }
}
```

**Message Class**

```
public class Message
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid MessageID { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }

    public Guid SenderID { get; set; }

    public virtual User Sender { get; set; }

    public Guid AddresseeID { get; set; }

    public virtual User Addressee{ get; set; }

}
```

**Update/Edit:**

I wanted to add some extra detail to the question to help explain better.

I have implemented a repository pattern. So with the above classes I can easily get all messages that the user has sent. E.g.

```
messageRepository.GetMessagesFromUserByUserID(Guid.Parse(id)).ToList();

public IEnumerable<Message> GetMessagesFromUserByUserID(Guid userID)
        {
            return context.Messages.Where(x => x.SenderID == userID).ToList();
        }
```

This is all fine. The problem is that I would like to use the Sender navigational property to get the sender's name, so when the client gets the messages they can see who they are from.

I could use my user repository, look up the User by UserID and combine the two results - but this seems counter intuitive.

Finally; I apologies for not being able to phrase this in a concise way and hope the extra info helps.

Update 2:

I have tried to use the Sender property eg. `Sender.Name` however I recieve an error. I went to look in the DB and found  this is what is being produced. Please ignore the fact that the Guids are the same.

[image: Database Image]

Comment: It looks good for me. The question is more suitable for [code review site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: OK so sounds like I have made a start. My confusion has shifted to how  I tell EF that `SentMessages` are messages where the UserID == SenderID and similar for `ReceivedMessages`. I think this is all to do with navigational properties. I will add some extra detail to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Ladislav Mrnka for confirming the properties right, that helped a lot.

So my answer was inspired from another SO question. I just needed to add some detail to the model builder like so:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Message>()
                .HasRequired(m => m.Sender)
                .WithMany(t => t.MessagesSent)
                .HasForeignKey(m => m.SenderID)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Message>()
                .HasRequired(m => m.Addressee)
                .WithMany(t => t.MessagesReceived)
                .HasForeignKey(m => m.AddresseeID)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```